# Issue accessing Hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures, data-dumper

I have a Hash of following structure in perl -

```
my %testHash = (
        KeyL1 => {
            KeyLL1 => {
                KeyLLL1 => [1,2],
                KeyLLL2 => [2,3],
            },
            KeyLL2 => {
                KeyLLL1 => [1,2],
                KeyLLL2 => [2,3],
            },
            KeyLL3 => {
                KeyLLL1 => [1,2],
                KeyLLL2 => [2,3],
            },            
        },
        KeyL2 => {
            KeyLL1 => {
                KeyLLL1 => [1,2],
                KeyLLL2 => [2,3],
            },
            KeyLL2 => {
                KeyLLL1 => [1,2],
                KeyLLL2 => [2,3],
            },
            KeyLL3 => {
                KeyLLL1 => [1,2],
                KeyLLL2 => [2,3],
            }, 
        },
        );
```

Now, when I am trying to access it the following way, I am getting 'undef' as a result

```
my %tempHash = $testHash{'KeyL1'};
print Data::Dumper::Dumper($tempHash{'KeyLL1'});
print Data::Dumper::Dumper($tempHash{'KeyLL1'}{'KeyLLL1'});
```

Result --

```
$VAR1 = undef; $VAR1 = undef;
```

Please point to me what am I doing wrong. I am pretty new to perl.

Comment: ***Always*** `use strict`  and `use warnings 'all'` in every Perl program you write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `$testHash{'KeyL1'}` is a hashref, not a hash.

Hashrefs are scalars. `my %tempHash =` is not expecting a scalar.

You need to dereference it:

```
my %tempHash = %{$testHash{'KeyL1'}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could do it this way if its just about viewing the structures.

**Also try:**

```
print Dumper $testHash{KeyL1} ;
print Dumper $testHash{KeyL1}{KeyLL1} ;
print Dumper $testHash{KeyL1}{KeyLL1}{KeyLLL1} ;
```

**Output:**

```
%_Host@User> ./hash.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'KeyLL1' => {
                        'KeyLLL2' => [
                                       2,
                                       3
                                     ],
                        'KeyLLL1' => [
                                       1,
                                       2
                                     ]
                      },
          'KeyLL2' => {
                        'KeyLLL2' => [
                                       2,
                                       3
                                     ],
                        'KeyLLL1' => [
                                       1,
                                       2
                                     ]
                      },
          'KeyLL3' => {
                        'KeyLLL2' => [
                                       2,
                                       3
                                     ],
                        'KeyLLL1' => [
                                       1,
                                       2
                                     ]
                      }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'KeyLLL2' => [
                         2,
                         3
                       ],
          'KeyLLL1' => [
                         1,
                         2
                       ]
        };
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2
        ];
%_Host@User>
```